# How to use beoreRouteEnter with composition api

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, vue-router

i am creating a page in which there is a condition from a file if the condition is true then the user should be vaigated to the page else it should show error404 page.I Need to use composition api i knoew its easy to achieve with option api as beforeRouteEnter is not available in composion api docs.

```
<script setup>
beforeRouteEnter((to, from, next) => {
  if (condition) {
    next({
      name: "Error404Page",
      params: { pathMatch: "/some-path" },
    });
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
</script
```

basically i need to pass a condition for each page if the condition is true then show the page else show error page404 not found

Comment: setup happens when comp instance is created. This doesn't go well with the concept that the hook should happen before view instance is resolved and created.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Nuxt 3, your best bet to achieve this behaviour is to create a [middleware](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/middleware) file and bind it to the page.

1. Define file `/middleware/check.js` with following:

```js
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to, from) => {
 if (/*condition*/) {
   return navigateTo('/some-path-to-error-page');
 }
 // else do nothing and just let Nuxt navigate to your page
}
```

2. inside your page component (e.g. `/pages/my-page.vue`) in the `<script setup>` section add:

```js
definePageMeta({
  middleware: 'check'
})
```

This will run `check.js` everytime `/my-page` is visited and will automatically redirect if the condition is met.

You can also define "global" middleware file just by chaning the file name to `/middleware/check.global.js` - such file will automatically run before EACH routing event (in alphabetical order in case there are more global middlewares) without any additional config.